# Zeit/Now - Update existing deployment without changing link - is it possible?

Tags: vercel

I have a vue.js app hosted at `now`. It is an already compiled build, which was hosted with just `now --public`, without json building and stuff. And I wonder if it is ever possible to add files/assets or change/update files within the very this deployment, without changing deployment URL or creating new deployment. And if it is, what is the easiest way to do so?

My question may sound silly, but I've referred wherever I could and failed to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of adding files to an existing deployment.

> **Deployment Immutability**
>
> *It is worth pointing out that there is no notion of editing or
>   modifying an existing deployment. When you make a source or config
>   change, a new deployment is always created.*
>   https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/concepts/immutability/

Instead you should use deployment [Aliases](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/domains-and-aliases/aliasing-a-deployment/) to keep a single url for your project.